# iOS - change app-name after app upgrade to full version via inApp-purchase

Tags: ios6, in-app-purchase

I'd like to create a lite version of my app and allow the user to upgrade to the full version via inApp-purchase.

When the user downloads the free version of the app it is named  lite.
Is there any possibility to change the name after the upgrade to the full version programmatically? It makes no sense to show  lite after the upgrade so I'd like to change the name simply to .

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app name cannot be changed. I had started down the same road a few years ago. The app name and connection to Apple is the bundle id, which is unique for each app.
And, it might be a difficult proposition to change the default app image after an upgrade.

I resolved this by using a limited set of features for the "lite" version, which I give away as a free download.
I have two scenarios: 1) purchase one of the feature "sets" or 2) a full upgrade.
If the user wants only a "set", they purchase that set.
If the user wishes the "full" version, they pay for the upgrade. The upgrade unlocks all of the features.
I do this through a check for "upgrade" or "purchase" via InApp Purchasing.
After upgrade, I remove the "upgrade button" and unlock all of the features.
Good luck.